# Проблема со спецсимволами &amp;

Tags: php, html, битрикс

Сверяю парсером мета теги со старым сайтом. Выдает ошибку на несовпадении символов на старом написано просто `&amp;` а на новом `&amp;amp;`

Добавляю description на новый сайт через SetPageProperty

```
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", "&amp;Каталог запчастей!");
```

на новом сайте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на старом сайте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: При таком изменении появляется странный знак)

```
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", html_entity_decode("&amp;Каталог запчастей!"));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите что можно сделать?

Comment: Превратить `&amp;` обратно в html-сущность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью `html_entity_decode` `&amp;` будет превращен в `&` и затем в битриксовых недрах превращен обратно в `&amp;`:

```
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", html_entity_decode("&amp;Каталог запчастей!"));
```

Comment: У меня заменился на такой знак "⚙" )

Comment: Ну а в html страницы что видно?

Comment: один минус использования html_entity_decode в битриксе. Если открыть SEO в панели управления, то это описание не выводиться